# Reading data from airspeed v3 eagle tree

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, i2c

I am trying to get values from this sensor **Airspeed v3** from eagle tree but it seems my I2C is not working properly.

I bought a module in third party mode and followed these [instructions](http://www.eagletreesystems.com/Manuals/microsensor-i2c.pdf) from the manufacturer website.

I went to rcgroups forum and discovered the right values for the bits mentioned in the documentation about WRITE and READ.

I started the development of a code but I cannot get the values from the sensor. It is supposed to send me a 2 byte-formatted value indicating the airspeed measured. But surprisingly when I call this method `Wire.requestFrom(AIRSPEED_ADDRESS, 2)` it returns 0, so someway the communication is not working. I have used I2C before for ADXL345 sensor and it works perfectly.

The results from these lines

```
Serial.println(data[0]);  
Serial.println(data[1]);
```

are just -1 indicating that no data is available to display.

Does anybody know how to get this working? Am I missing something?

This is my code right now.

```
#include <Wire.h>

#define AIRSPEED_ADDRESS  0xEA
#define WRITE_BIT         0x00
#define READ_BIT          0x01


void setup() {
  // join I2C bus (I2Cdev library doesn't do this automatically)
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Program started");
}

void loop() {
  byte data[2] = {0};
  int i = 0;
  int16_t velocidade = 0;

  Wire.beginTransmission(AIRSPEED_ADDRESS);  
  if (!Wire.write(WRITE_BIT)) {
    Serial.println("error sending write_bit");
  }
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.beginTransmission(AIRSPEED_ADDRESS);  
  if (!Wire.write(0x07)) {
    Serial.println("error sending 0x07");
  }
  Wire.endTransmission(false);

  Wire.beginTransmission(AIRSPEED_ADDRESS);  
  if (!Wire.write(READ_BIT)) {
    Serial.println("error sending read_bit");
  }
  else {
    //Serial.println("ok sending read_bit");
  }  
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.beginTransmission(AIRSPEED_ADDRESS);  
  Serial.print("bytes read from slave: ");
  Serial.println(  Wire.requestFrom(AIRSPEED_ADDRESS, 2) );
  data[0] = Wire.read();
  data[1] = Wire.read();
  Wire.endTransmission(); 

  velocidade = data[1] | (data[0] << 8);
  Serial.println(data[0]);  
  Serial.println(data[1]);  
  Serial.println(" ");  

}
```

Comment: This is really helpful. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's interesting but after using a different library the code worked out.

It has to follow exactly what the datasheet says in order to get things done.

The following source code makes it and get the airspeed from the sensor:

```
#define SENSOR_ADDRESS 0xEA 
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <I2cMaster.h> 
TwiMaster AIRSPEED_SENSOR(true); 

void setup() { 
  Serial.begin(9600); 
}

long airspeed_update(void) { 
  static struct { 
    union { int16_t val; uint8_t raw[2]; 
    } airspeed16; 
  } airspeedv3; 

  long airsp;    

  if(AIRSPEED_SENSOR.start(SENSOR_ADDRESS | I2C_WRITE)) { 
    delay(10);   
    AIRSPEED_SENSOR.write(0x07);  
    delay(10); 
    AIRSPEED_SENSOR.stop(); 
  } 

  if(AIRSPEED_SENSOR.restart(SENSOR_ADDRESS | I2C_READ)) { 
    delay(10);  
    airspeedv3.airspeed16.raw[0]=AIRSPEED_SENSOR.read(false); 
    delay(10); 
    airspeedv3.airspeed16.raw[1]=AIRSPEED_SENSOR.read(true); 
    delay(10); 
    AIRSPEED_SENSOR.stop();
  } 

  airsp=airspeedv3.airspeed16.val; 
  return airsp; 
}

void loop() {    
  int airspeed = airspeed_update(); Serial.println(airspeed); 
  delay(50);
}
```

Get this library from [here](https://github.com/landis/arduino/tree/master/libraries/I2cMaster).

Answer (score 2):

I found the I2C address on my Eagletree Airspeed V3 sensor to be 0x75 NOT 0xEA.

the following code adapted from first sample above works on my Nano:

```
/*
 * note that timming is critical - see delay (5)
 * and bps set to 115200
 * works ok, but clean up 5-19-2019 jaf
 */

#include <Wire.h>

#define AIRSPEED_ADDRESS  0x75
#define WRITE_BIT         0x00
#define READ_BIT          0x01


void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Program started");
}

void loop() {
  byte data[2] = {0};
  int i = 0;

  Wire.beginTransmission(AIRSPEED_ADDRESS);  
  Wire.write(WRITE_BIT); 
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.beginTransmission(AIRSPEED_ADDRESS);  
  Wire.write(0x07); 
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.beginTransmission(AIRSPEED_ADDRESS);  
  Wire.write(READ_BIT); 
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.beginTransmission(AIRSPEED_ADDRESS);  
  Wire.requestFrom(AIRSPEED_ADDRESS, 2);
  data[0] = Wire.read();
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Serial.println(data[0]);  
  delay(5);
}
```